# Using a function to create a string from numbers

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy

I am trying to create a function in python that returns the top 10 IDs, by a given column, as a string that will be the value of a new column. For example, if the top 10 ids are [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], the output should be "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10". When I apply the function I have, it just returns blank values.

For context here is what my dataset HF_2018 looks like:
[image]

Here is my current function:

```
def top_ten(month):
top_funds = ""
top_ten = np.array(HF_2018[HF_2018['month']==month-1].nlargest(10, 'Performance')['Fund_ID'])
for i in top_ten:
    top_funds += str(i)
return top_funds
```

And here is how I am trying to create the new column:

```
HF_2018['top_10'] = top_ten(HF_2018['month'])
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One way to form a string from an array of numbers is to use `astype` to convert them to individual strings:

```
In [206]: x = np.arange(5)
In [207]: x.astype('U5')
Out[207]: array(['0', '1', '2', '3', '4'], dtype='<U5')
```

Then use `join` to concatenate them with what ever separator you want:

```
In [208]: ' '.join(x.astype('U5'))
Out[208]: '0 1 2 3 4'
```